# Storage viewer: Can't find indexedDB database originating from localhost

Tags: indexeddb, firefox-developer-tools

I've been working on a Firefox add-on which uses indexedDB to create a database locally. However, I am unable to see the contents of my database using the Storage viewer in Firefox web developer tools. When I expand below "Indexed DB" in the Storage tab I see various domain names, but not the name of my database, nor localhost. I also keep getting the message "No data present for selected host" no matter where I click.

(I would post a screenshot, but the system won't let me as I am too new here.)

Does the Storage browser always have problems finding locally created databases? Or could this indicate that my database isn't being created properly? My add-on code seems to be able to access it just fine, though.

All suggestions welcome.

Thanks,
Sara

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon the same problem recently while developing a web app for Firefox OS. First it wouldn't work, too. Then I got it to work when removing the hash-portion (including the hash) from the URL. It seems that the Storage Viewer can only find the db for URLs without the hash. Do have a hash in the URL?

Hope it helps.

Regards,
Erich

Comment: Have the same problem here. You may be right with the hash-Problem. My App works with angular templates and this requires the #/ in the url.

Opened a bug ticket:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1302989

Comment: Solved it for me, thanks!  Broken in Firefox Quantum.

Comment: @Brad Yup seems to be broken again, though if I remove the hash, there is still nothing in the db, even though the app works!